# How i can export a WindowBuilder to use it in a MacOSX

Tags: java

I created a calculator and exported it using:

> Project > Export > Runnable JAR file

I selected the option Package required libraries into generated JAR.
It works in my own PC but when I send the `.jar` to my MACOSX it doesn't work.
When I gave permissions to the project and clicked it again it drop the next message

I tried to install JRE and used

> $ ls -l@
> -rw-r--r--@
>
> 1 dave  staff  17663235 13 Oct 11:08 server-0.28.2-java8.jar
> com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms         619 com.apple.quarantine
> 68

and deleted the atributes with

> xattr -c file.jar

It doesn't work. What's wrong with my procedure ?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Ant, Maven, Gradle?

Comment: @thetechnician94 apparently, there's a problem with the version of JDK im using I compiled it with 14.0.1 and the MacOSX has 13.0.2 version instaled. but it says that it the last version available. I tried to change the modulepath of the project from the IDE (Eclipse) but it throws the same err
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class swingb.Calculadora
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: swingb/Calculadora has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 57.0